# Service is called multiple times inside NgRx Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

When I dispatch an action, service is called more than one time inside effect and I have to use "exhaustMap" instead of "concatMap" or "mergeMap" in all effects every time, and I do not know how it happened suddenly because it was OK before.
And I know that I do not dispatch one action before one time but it calls the service more than one time (in this case two times).

I imported effect in contact module like this:

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([PersonalContactEffects]),
StoreModule.forFeature(personalContactFeatureKey, personalContactReducer)
```

and the Effect is:

```
        loadPersonalContacts$ = createEffect(
        () => this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(personalContactActions.loadPersonalContactsList),
            tap(action => console.log("before service call", action)),
            concatMap(action => this.contactService.getList(action.query)),
            map(personalContactList => personalContactActions.personalContactsListLoaded({ personalContactList })),
            catchError(() => of(personalContactActions.setLoading({ loading: false })))
        )
    );
```

and I dispatch this action like this:

```
this.store.dispatch(fromPersonalContactActions.loadPersonalContactsList({ query }));
```

[image]

[image]

Beside above issue, I've got noticed that every Reducer is called twice every time an action is dispatched. And all these issues happen from the time when I imported "StoreModule.forFeature" to other lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Have you added a short debug `tap` in your effect to _ensure_ that it's not called twice? Being sure is not the same as having ensured...

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I logged it, and I am sure about calling the service twice in the Effect.

Comment: It seems like something is registered twice, Could you create a reproduction?

Comment: @timdeschryver Could you please explain more? What should I do?

Comment: replicate this behavior in a project that you can share GitHub/Stackblitz/...

Comment: without the full reproduction it's very hard to tell, where did you dispatch`loadPersonalContactsList`, could you provide git/stackblitz link?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could find the answer, and this is because of

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({...})
```

in appModule, and I commented it, so it does not call services twice inside effects and also does not call reducers twice. As mentioned in below links in github:

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1054

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1325